# Pass Multiple Checkboxes to PHP via Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

User has option to select from checkboxes. I want to get the checkbox as an array via jquery, then pass to php thru ajax. It doesnt seem that I am able to get array and process. I've seen other answers on SO, but none seem to work.

HTML/PHP

```
<?php foreach ( $results['buckets'] as $bucket ) { ?>
    <div><?php echo $bucket->name ?></div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="buckets[]" id="<?php echo strtolower( $bucket->name ) ?>" class="buckets" value="<?php echo $bucket->id ?>" style="visibility: hidden" /><label for="<?php echo strtolower( $bucket->name ) ?>" class="<?php echo strtolower( $bucket->name ) ?>"><?php echo $bucket->name ?></label>
<?php } ?>
```

JS

```
$( function() {

    $( "#form" ).submit( function() {

        var buckets = new Array();
        $( "input[name='buckets[]']:checked" ).each( function() {
                buckets.push( $( this ).val() );
        } );
        var valid = false;

        $.ajax( {

            type: "POST",
            url: "/scripts/validateBucketSelect.php",
            data: buckets,
            cache: false,
            async: false,

            success: function( error ) {

                if ( error == "null" ){

                    valid = true;

                } else {

                    $( ".errorMessage" ).html( error );
                }
            }
        } );

        return valid;
    } );
} );
```

PHP

```
$postData = $_POST;

if ( count( $postData['buckets'] ) < 3 ) {
    echo "Oops! You have to select at least 3 buckets.";
} elseif ( count( $postData['buckets'] ) > 5 ) {
    echo "Oops! You cannot select more than 5 buckets.";
} else {
    echo "null";
}
```

Comment: checked the js to see if `buckets` is populated? checked the php to see if `POST` is populated - a little debugging goes a long way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`buckets` is an array, but you need the `key` in the php script.

So `data: buckets,` should be `data: {buckets : buckets}`, then you could get with `$_POST['buckets']`.

If you just use 
`data: buckets,`, then the `$_POST` is already the data you want.